# WPF How to bind object from window to custom user control

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I need to create a custom user control and pass it from the main window an object. I need to display the object's attribute inside the user control, how can i do it? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: This is my code, what i'm doing wrong?

My custom control:

```
  public partial class DetailsComponent : UserControl
{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ModelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Model", typeof(bool), typeof(DetailsComponent), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public ModelClass Model
    {
        get { return (ModelClass)GetValue(ModelProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ModelProperty, value);

        }
    }


    public DetailsComponent()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

usercontrol.xaml.cs:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp3.DetailsComponent"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp3"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock></TextBlock>-->
    </StackPanel>
    
</Grid>
```

MainWindows.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp3" xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:LoadingSpinnerControl;assembly=LoadingSpinnerControl" xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

<Grid>
    <local:DetailsComponent Model="{Binding Model}"></local:DetailsComponent>
</Grid>
```

MainWindows.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
   
    ModelClass Model = null;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

      

        Model = new ModelClass("hi", "hi", "hi");
        DataContext = this;
    
    }

  }
```

ModelClass.cs:

```
 public class ModelClass
{
    public ModelClass(string name, string description, string city)
    {
        Name = name;
        Description = description;
        City = city;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The control should expose a bindable property, i.e. a dependency property.

Comment: @Clemens i have updated the answer with the code, I created a dependencyProperty but it still not work

Comment: Remove `DataContext = this;` from the control constructor and write `"{Binding Model.Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"` in its XAML. A control must never set its own DataContext, because that breaks the standard data binding behavior.

Comment: Also make sure that `Model` in MainWindow is a public property, not a field. I strongly suggest to read [Data Binding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-6.0).

Comment: And `typeof(bool)` in the dependency property registration is wrong.

Comment: A note on software design, your control should certainly not have a dependency on a ModelClass. You may instead have 3 dependency properties of type string for Name, Description and City.

Comment: So you are creating a Model property that is outside of inheriting data context, one of the biggest advantages of WPF, and you completely ignore DatContext. Why are you going around in circles of obvious solution, which is DataContext property?

Comment: Also from the code as it reads now, your DetailsComponent User Control is completely redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Model` must be defined as a public *property* for you to be able to bind to it:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ModelClass Model { get;  }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Model = new ModelClass("hi", "hi", "hi");
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

The `DetailsModel` should not set its own `DataContext` property because then you cannot bind to the `Model` property of its inherited `DataContext`:

```
public partial class DetailsComponent : UserControl
{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ModelProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("Model", typeof(ModelClass), typeof(DetailsComponent), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public ModelClass Model
    {
        get { return (ModelClass)GetValue(ModelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ModelProperty, value); }
    }

    public DetailsComponent()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

You could bind to the `Name` property of the `Model` dependency property using a `RelativeSource` binding:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp3.DetailsComponent"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp3"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Model.Name, 
                           RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</UserControl
```